# WCF , Uploading byte[] takes longs time

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

i got a iis hosted wcf service with a function that get a file and store it on the server

I did some test with a 6.5mb file , it took me to upload it 4.6min allthough it should take about 2 min,

Anyone know how can i speed up the process ? i really need the upload to be faster

```
ServiceManager.UploadFile(fileName, FilesHelper.FileToByteArray(filePath));


 public static ServiceCallResult UploadFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Logger.StopwatchInit();
            VsServiceClient vs = new VsServiceClient();
            EndPointSelector(vs); 
            vs.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            try
            {
                bool result = vs.UploadMediaFile(fileName, data);;
                sw.StopAndLog(fileName);
                return new ServiceCallResult() { IsSuccessful = result };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sw.StopAndLog(fileName,ex);
                return new ServiceCallResult() { IsSuccessful = false , Message = ex.Message };
            }
            finally
            {

                vs.Close();
            }
        }




<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" maxBufferSize="160000000" maxBufferPoolSize="160000000"
     maxReceivedMessageSize="160000000">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="160000000" maxStringContentLength="160000000"
      maxArrayLength="160000000" maxBytesPerRead="160000000" maxNameTableCharCount="160000000" />
    </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="vsAjaxBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="vsServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="vsServiceBehavior" name="VsService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="vsAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="VsService" />
   </service>
```

The web service runs on EC2 small instance server with iis7 , the code inside the service function take less then 1 second, so all the wasted time is on the client to server transfer.

Another thing , the server is not in used so most of the time only one single user uses it...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx). Anyway there is always significant time difference between direct upload and WCF upload because WCF has a lot of additional processing and abstraction but the time you are reporting is really high.